# Retrieve AWS secrets using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

I want to retrieve AWS secrets using python boto3 and I came across this sample code:

- [aws-doc-sdk-examples/python/example_code/secretsmanager/get_secret_value.py at main · awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples · GitHub](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/example_code/secretsmanager/get_secret_value.py)
- [Secrets Manager examples using SDK for Python (Boto3) - AWS SDK Code Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/python_3_secrets-manager_code_examples.html)

But it is confusing. I don't see boto3 library import in the python file. Not an expert of Python, so any help in understanding this much appreciated.

I was expecting to have the AWS secrets name and boto3 libarary as part of the python function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/python#readme), each of the example folders has one or more main runner scripts.

For the Secrets Manager examples, you would run either:

1. python scenario_get_secret.py, or
2. python scenario_get_batch_secrets.py

Each of these 'runner' scripts imports the relevant Python code e.g. [get_secret_value.py](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/example_code/secretsmanager/get_secret_value.py).

The code is structured this way so that you can easily test the code while separating the test code from the reusable utility code (that you would potentially use).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. So if I want to use the code for  retrieving secrets (batch) from my AWS account, I can use scenario_get_batch_secrets.py right?

Comment: You can run scenario_get_batch_secrets.py to get a batch of secrets. If you're planning to use the code is a more general-purpose fashion, as part of an application , then you would use batch_get_secret_value.py as a sort of library or interface to Secrets Manager.

Answer (score 0):

To work with AWS Secrets Manager using the boto3 library in Python, you indeed need to import the boto3 library first. Additionally, to retrieve a secret, you need to know the name or the ARN (Amazon Resource Name) of the secret you wish to retrieve.

Here's a simple, complete example that demonstrates how to import the boto3 library and retrieve a secret from AWS Secrets Manager. This example assumes you have already set up your AWS credentials in a way that boto3 can automatically detect them (for example, by using the AWS CLI and running aws configure).

```py
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def get_secret(secret_name):
    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')

    try:
        # Attempt to retrieve the secret value
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        # Handle the exception if the secret can't be retrieved
        raise e

    # If there's no exception, process the retrieved secret
    if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
        secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
    else:
        # For binary secrets, decode them before using
        secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'].decode('utf-8')
    return secret

# Example usage
secret_name = 'your_secret_name_here'
secret_value = get_secret(secret_name)
print(secret_value)
```

I hope this helps